Very simple simple custom phpcs (phpcbf) fixing sniff fails
I am attempting to write a little simple phpcs (phpcbf) sniff to remove whitespace within empty curly braces. I've written quite a few small fixers, and this seemed like it should be very easy.
Basically with the move to promoted parameters, we're ending up with various whitespace setups inside the empty curly braces following the construct like
public function __construct( protected string $cdnPath ) {
}

public function __construct( protected string $cdnPath ) { }

public function __construct( protected string $cdnPath ) {}

I just want to unify these on {}
The sniff as I have it so far
<?php

use PHP_CodeSniffer\Files\File;
use PHP_CodeSniffer\Sniffs\Sniff;

class CurlyBraceInnerWhiteSpaceSniff implements Sniff {

    public function register() : array {
        return [
            T_OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param int $stackPtr
     */
    public function process( File $phpcsFile, $stackPtr ) : void {
        $tokens = $phpcsFile->getTokens();
        if( $tokens[$stackPtr + 1]['code'] !== T_WHITESPACE ) {
            return;
        }

        $closePtr = $phpcsFile->findNext(T_WHITESPACE, $stackPtr + 1, null, true);
        if( $tokens[$closePtr]['code'] !== T_CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET ) {
            return;
        }

        $fix = $phpcsFile->addFixableError('There must be no whitespace inside empty curly braces', $stackPtr + 1, 'CurlyBraceInnerWhiteSpace');
        if( $fix ) {
            $phpcsFile->fixer->beginChangeset();
            for( $i = $stackPtr + 1; $i < $closePtr; $i++ ) {
                $phpcsFile->fixer->replaceToken($i, '');
            }
            $phpcsFile->fixer->endChangeset();
        }
    }
}


It takes a VERY long time before giving up
running phpcbf with the -v reveals many many entries like this with [made 50 passes]... ERROR
Processing TransformCommand.php [PHP => 636 tokens in 89 lines]... DONE in 11ms (1 fixable violations)
        => Fixing file: 1/1 violations remaining [made 50 passes]... ERROR in 585ms

I found in the documentation somewhere that adding return $phpcsFile->numTokens; to process could help, by preventing the sniff from running against the same file twice, but it has not seemed to help at all.

The problem was that I had another sniff from another collection fighting my sniff.
It wants to replace {} with {  }. Having the two sniffs fighting caused the back and forth which is why it would try 50 times before giving up.

The SpacesInsideParenthesesFixer could be converted into a SpacesInsideCurlyBracketsFixer.
Not exactly sure how it would behave with new-line, but there's also example patterns for that.

That is a PHP-CS-Fixer rule, which is an entirely different though similarly named tool. I am using phpcs.

Your implementation doesn't catch empty lines or Allman-style bracing. I'd start by using the Generic.Functions.OpeningFunctionBraceKernighanRitchie sniff to make sure your open brace is on the same line. Then, note that the tokens array contains the scope level and the position of the matching closing brace:
Array
(
    [type] => T_OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET
    [code] => PHPCS_T_OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET
    [content] => {
    [line] => 3
    [column] => 1
    [length] => 1
    [bracket_opener] => 5
    [bracket_closer] => 20
    [scope_condition] => 1
    [scope_opener] => 5
    [scope_closer] => 20
    [level] => 0
    [conditions] => Array
        (
        )
)

So your sniff would basically become, "if this is a class method (i.e., level 1) and the only thing between the braces is whitespace, raise an error."
public function process(File $phpcsFile, $stackPtr): void
{
    $tokens = $phpcsFile->getTokens();
    // If the close immediately follows the open, we're good.
    $opener = $tokens[$stackPtr]['bracket_opener'];
    $closer = $tokens[$stackPtr]['bracket_closer'];
    if ($closer - $opener === 1) {
        return;
    }
    // Scan all the tokens between the open and close.
    for ($i = $opener + 1; $i < $closer; $i++) {
        // As soon as we find anything that's not whitespace, we're ok.
        if ($tokens[$i]['code'] !== T_WHITESPACE) {
            return;
        }
    }
    // Otherwise, all we had between open and close was whitespace.
    $fix = $phpcsFile->addFixableError(...);
    if ($fix) {
        $phpcsFile->fixer->beginChangeset();
        for ($i = $opener + 1; $i < $closer; $i++) {
            $phpcsFile->fixer->replaceToken($i, '');
        }
        $phpcsFile->fixer->endChangeset();
    }
}

You might also want to apply this only to class methods named __construct. You could find the start of the function declaration with $tokens[$stackPtr]['scope_condition'] and then work forward to find the name.
Before:
<?php
class Foo
{
    public function __construct() {
    
    
    }
}

Command:
% vendor/bin/phpcbf --standard=custom Foo.php
PHPCBF RESULT SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------
FILE                               FIXED  REMAINING
---------------------------------------------------
/home/alex/temp/Foo.php            1      0
---------------------------------------------------
A TOTAL OF 1 ERROR WERE FIXED IN 1 FILE
---------------------------------------------------

Time: 38ms; Memory: 6MB

After:
<?php
class Foo
{
    public function __construct() {}
}


I don't see why my existing code would have any issues with Allman-style bracing? It's completely agnostic to everything before the opening curly brace? You're correct about the newlines. That's coming out as two T_WHITESPACE tokens rather than one, so I'll need to scan for that. Easy enough.
Your code however is giving me the same exact Fixing file: 1/1 violations remaining [made 50 passes]... ERROR in 373ms same as my version

If you have the open brace on the line after the function name, and then immediately have the close brace, your code accepts this as valid. I'm assuming you want to raise an alert in this case, but I realize this isn't the responsibility of your sniff -- which is why I recommend also adding the K&R sniff.

I updated my as-exists example to handle newlines. It still of course suffers the same issue.

I believe you'll find that the error is on the fix, not the detect. Your existing fix won't work, you'll need to update it to scan between $opener and $closer.

All I want from my sniff is to replace { (any amount of vertical/horizontal whitespace) } with {}, globally, at any level - a syntax aware preg_replace('/\{\s+}/', '{}', $source)

Then just remove the level check.

Then just remove the level check that's fine and good, but the code doesn't work even with it. The fix fails. It tries it 50 times and gives up.

So… I feel like an idiot… I think I found the problem. Something in our current suite of sniffs is replacing {} with {  } (two spaces?) already. They're fighting. That's the issue.
